# J2EE Framework Spring Hibernate Multi-Tenant Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I need to develop a multi tenant application using the framework J2EE, Spring and Hibernate. For many reasons, I adopted the Shared Application/Shared Database architecture. A tenant ID column in each of the table identifies the tenant to which the user information belongs.
After many researches for examples of how to implement this method, I have found that there is a bug in discriminator-based multi-tenancy (HHH-6054), according to this link :

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6054

So, how to implement this method ? How to get the tenant ID and the User ID after authentication in order to use them in DAO Implmentation classes to add/update/delete/select a record? And are there some configuration that should be set?

Many thanks for your help.
Best Regards,